# Enabling WiFi Monitor Mode on HTC Inspire 4G

Tags: wi-fi

Is it possible to enable WiFi Monitor Mode( promiscuous mode ) on HTC Inspire 4G? Or is it possible on any android phone?

Answer (score 1):

I had an android for a long time before I got my windows phone (still prefer android), and I used an app called Network Monitor.

Here's the link to it:

http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/tools/network-monitor_biuf.html

I had a htc inspire as well, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: OP want to turn on promiscuous mode not monitor wifi usage.